# Generating Random Color and Assigning it to object

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, arc4random

I want to make `Obstacle_Color = random` color instead of *blackcolor*.
I found random color implementation but couldn't merge `Obstacle_Color with the return val of rand method. Thanks in advance!

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class AKObstacle: SKSpriteNode {

    let Obstacle_Width: CGFloat = 40.0
    let Obstacle_Height: CGFloat = 70.0
    let Obstacle_Color = UIColor.blackColor()

    init(){

        let size = CGSizeMake(Obstacle_Width, Obstacle_Height)
        super.init(texture: nil, color: Obstacle_Color, size: size)

        loadPhysicsBoadyWithSize(size)
        startMoving()

    }
```

---

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

    var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make get randomcolor a static function and call it as a class method. Another one (probably better, since that function doesn't seem to be specifically linked to that class) is to make it a public method. Also someone else suggested to call it in the constructor, which also works.

### Solution 1

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class AKObstacle: SKSpriteNode {

    let Obstacle_Width: CGFloat = 40.0
    let Obstacle_Height: CGFloat = 70.0
    let Obstacle_Color = AKObstacle.getRandomColor()

    init() { ... }

    static func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {

        var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class AKObstacle: SKSpriteNode {

    let Obstacle_Width: CGFloat = 40.0
    let Obstacle_Height: CGFloat = 70.0
    let Obstacle_Color = getRandomColor()

    init() {...}

}

public func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {

    var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
super.init(texture: nil, color: getRandomColor(), size: size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `self` before `super.init` call. You can implement an extension of `UIColor` class

```
class MyClass: SKSpriteNode {

    let Obstacle_Width: CGFloat = 40.0
    let Obstacle_Height: CGFloat = 70.0

    init(){

        let size = CGSizeMake(Obstacle_Width, Obstacle_Height)

        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.Obstacle_Color(), size: size)

    }
}

extension UIColor{

    class func Obstacle_Color() -> UIColor {

        var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```